# Why are my seeds disappearing?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Minecraft when I planted and bonemealed some seeds, then broke them, only to see that my seed drop disappeared and I was left with only a piece of wheat. I searched my whole entire inventory, but there were no seeds, and I had no hoppers or hopper minecarts nearby that could have possible collected the seeds. I am using the regular texture pack, with Vanilla Minecraft 1.17 on Bedrock Edition(PE) in a singleplayer world.

Comment: Long shot, but... have you changed the "tile drops" setting, or are you in adventure mode instead of survival?

Comment: I also have this problem too! I believe that it is a bug, but im  not 100% sure. I break the wheat, and it only sometimes drops seeds.

Answer (score 2):

When you harvest wheat, there is always a chance for it to not drop any seeds, while it will always drop 1 wheat. From the [wiki article on wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat):

> When a fully-grown wheat crop is harvested, it drops 1 wheat and 0 to 3 wheat seeds. A wheat crop has a total of eight stages (0-7) from the time it is planted until it can be harvested. If a crop is harvested before it is fully grown, it drops one seed. Wheat needs light to grow; a seed is destroyed if planted without light. Harvesting with a Fortune-enchanted tool increases the number of seeds dropped but does not increase the yield of wheat.

I do not know exact numbers for the different possible results, but it sounds like you're just getting some bad RNG, hope it turns around for you soon!